# Showing that $2c_1(f_*\mathscr O_X)=-f_*R_f$ on curves, maybe by local fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, local-fields, ramification

I originally asked this question on Mathematic StackExchange, but it did not seem to be attracting any attention, so now I am trying mathoverflow. I hope it is not too simple or unappropriate a question for this site, and if it is, then please may those in power feel free to delete it.

*I would like a way to see that $2c_1(f_*\mathscr O_X)=-f_*R_f,$ where $R_f$ is the ramification divisor of a finite morphism of smooth curves $f\colon X\to Y$ over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0.$*

I am aware that this follows directly from Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch and that it is precisely what is proven in exercise IV. 2.6 of Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry,* where it boils down to the local duality for a finite etale morphism. I would like to have a way of seeing it different from those two.

For instance [this paper](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/MasterJavanpeykar.pdf) states it is an easy calculation imitating Chapter 3.6, Proposition 13 of Serre's *Local Fields*. I do not see how that applies, so I would be very grateful for an *explanation of how methods of local fields can be applied to local calculations in algebraic geometry in general*, and specifically how to derive the above equality. That is not to say that I would be any lesss happy with a proof of the above equality by some entirely different methods.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Probably they are referring to a local analysis of the degeneracy locus of the trace pairing on $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$.  The trace pairing is equivalent to a homomorphism $f_*\mathcal{O}_X \to \textit{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{O}_Y)$, and this is injective in the tame case.  Applying the Whitney sum formula relates $c_1$ to the cokernel of this injective homomorphism.

Comment: That sounds very interesting. Could you perhaps write it out in more detail as an answer?

Comment: @user82454:  In general, the degeneracy locus of a generically surjective morphism $E \rightarrow F$ of vector bundles of the same rank is represented by $c_{1}(F)-c_{1}(E)$; all we have to do is note that $f_{\ast}R_f$  the degeneracy locus of Jason's homomorphism.

Comment: @YusufMustopa: If I understand correctly, you are refering to the Thom-Porteous formula?

Comment: @user82454:  I was indeed referring to the Thom-Porteous formula.  In any event, I'm glad Jason took the time to write the more informative answer below!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I looked at that section of *Local Fields*, and I believe this is about the trace pairing.  For a finite, flat morphism of Dedekind schemes, $f:X\to Y$, the pushforward sheaf $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is a locally free $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module, let's say of (constant) rank $n$.  It is also an algebra, i.e., multiplication is a $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module homomorphism, $$ \theta_f : f_*\mathcal{O}_X\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y} f_*\mathcal{O}_X \to f_*\mathcal{O}_X.$$ By adjunction of tensor and hom, this is equivalent to an $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module homomorphism, $$ \widetilde{\theta}_f:f_*\mathcal{O}_X \to \textit{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X,f_*\mathcal{O}_X).$$  But the target module, being End of a locally free sheaf, has a trace map in the usual sense of trace of matrices, $$\text{Tr}_{f_*\mathcal{O}_Y}:\textit{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X,f_*\mathcal{O}_X) \to \mathcal{O}_Y.$$  The composition with $\widetilde{\theta}_f$ is a trace map for $f$, $$ \text{Tr}_f:f_*\mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_Y.$$ The composition of this trace map with $\theta_f$ is a $\mathcal{O}_Y$-bilinear pairing on the locally free $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$, $$ T_f: f_*\mathcal{O}_X\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y} f_*\mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_Y.$$  This pairing is often called the "trace pairing".  Again, by adjunction of tensor and hom, it is equivalent to an $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module homomorphism, $$\widetilde{T}_f:f_*\mathcal{O}_X \to \textit{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{O}_Y).$$
In particular, taking the associated $n^{\text{th}}$ exterior power of both sides, i.e., taking the determinant, gives a morphism of invertible $\mathcal{O}_Y$-modules, $$\text{det}(\widetilde{T}_f): \text{det}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X) \to \textit{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(\text{det}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X),\mathcal{O}_Y).$$  If $f$ is generically étale, then $\text{det}(\widetilde{T}_f)$ is injective.  In this case, by definition, the **determinant** of $f$ is defined to be the unique invertible ideal sheaf $\mathfrak{d}_f$ of $\mathcal{O}_Y$ such that 
$$ \text{Image}(\text{det}(\widetilde{T}_f)) = \textit{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(\text{det}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X),\mathcal{O}_Y)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y}\mathfrak{d}_f,$$ as subsheaves of $\textit{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(\text{det}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X),\mathcal{O}_Y)$, i.e., $\text{det}(\widetilde{T}_f)$ is an isomorphism,
$$ \text{det}(\widetilde{T}_f): \text{det}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X) \xrightarrow{\cong} \textit{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(\text{det}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X),\mathcal{O}_Y)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y}\mathfrak{d}_f.$$

On the other hand, the **different** of $f$, $\mathfrak{D}_f$, is defined to be the <del>maximal</del> minimal invertible ideal sheaf on $X$, $$\iota:\mathfrak{D}_f \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X,$$ such that for the associated transpose, $$\iota^\dagger: \mathcal{O}_X \to \textit{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathfrak{D}_f,\mathcal{O}_X), $$ with its induced pushforward map under $f_*$, $$f_*\iota^\dagger: f_*\mathcal{O}_X \to f_*\textit{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathfrak{D}_f,\mathcal{O}_X), $$ the $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module homomorphism $\text{Tr}_f$ factors through $f_*\iota^\dagger$, i.e., there exists a (unique) $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module homomorphism, $$\tau_f:f_*\textit{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathfrak{D}_f,\mathcal{O}_X) \to \mathcal{O}_Y,$$ such that $\text{Tr}_f$ equals $\tau_f\circ f_*\iota^\dagger$. The **ramification divisor** of $f$, $R_f$, is the unique effective Cartier divisor of $X$ whose associated invertible sheaf equals $\mathfrak{D}_f$.  One of the basic computations, Chapter III.3, Proposition 6 on p. 50 of *Local Fields*, states that the pushforward Cartier divisor $f_*R_f$ equals the effective Cartier divisor on $Y$ associated to the ideal sheaf $\mathfrak{d}_f$, i.e., $$\mathfrak{d}_f = \text{Nm}_f(\mathfrak{D}_f),$$ where $\text{Nm}_f$ is the **norm** associated to $f$.  In particular, the $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module homomorphism $\text{det}(\widetilde{T}_f)$ above now becomes an isomorphism, $$ \text{det}(\widetilde{T}_f):\text{det}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X) \xrightarrow{\cong} \textit{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(\text{det}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X),\mathcal{O}_Y)(-f_*R_f).$$  Using adjunction of tensor and hom one last time, this is an isomorphism of invertible $\mathcal{O}_Y$-modules, $$\text{det}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y} \text{det}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X) \xrightarrow{\cong} \mathcal{O}_Y(-f_*R_f).$$  This is the identity that you asked about.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated answer! May I just ask what the morphism $\mu\colon f_*\mathcal O_X\otimes_{\mathcal O_Y} f_*\mathcal O_X\to f_*\mathcal O_X$ is?

Comment: @user82454:  That is the multiplication map.  The sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ is a sheaf of rings -- it has a multiplication map.  Thus the morphism of ringed spaces, $f$, makes $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ into a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_Y$-algebras with an $\mathcal{O}_Y$-bilinear multiplication map.

Comment: @user82454: Now I see what you are asking: $\mu$ is the same as $\theta$.  In "Local Fields", they use $\theta$, but I usually call this $\mu$.  So I slipped and called it $\mu$ in one place.  I fixed it now.

Comment: Cheers, now it all makes perfect sense. Morever, this was precisely the answer I was after: a clear exposition of just how notions of *Local Fields* apply in this context. Thank you again!

Comment: Actually, there is one detail more that I do not quite understand: where does the minus sign in $-f_*R$ come from? Does the calculation in *Local Fields* show that $f_*R_f$ is the divisor associated to the sheaf $\mathfrak d_f^{-1}$ or to $\mathfrak d_f$?

Comment: As far as I can tell, $R_f$ is actually the divisor corresponding to *codifferent*, the inverse of the different, and that is where the minus sign originates, but I am not sure if that is correct.